# Should tag wikis include links to non-official sites?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, tag-wiki

A recent suggested tag-wiki edit for example:

> *Glitch* is a web-based massively-multiplayer game which takes place inside the minds of eleven peculiarly imaginative Giants. If your
>   question is about glitches in a game, please use the [bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag
>   instead.
>
> - [*Glitch*](http://glitch.com/)
> - [Strategy](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/)
> - [Wiki](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Glitch_Wiki)
> - [Blog](http://glitch.com/)
> - [Twitter](http://twitter.com/playglitch)

The `glitch-strategy.com` URL (Strategy and Wiki links above) *isn't officially sponsored/sanctioned*, so I'm not sure if those sorts of links should be included.  It could lead to a slippery slope of including *every* resource for game *X* as people could argue "well, if you have leaguecraft.com on there then you obviously should have mobafire.com..." etc.

The reject button didn't bring up any particularly good reasons to refuse the edit (are all the reasons canned, you can't type one?), "Vandalism" for promotional things seemed a bit extreme.

Comment: IMHO, yes. It would be helpful to include *useful* links to community/unofficial sites. What new WoW player wouldn't appreciate knowing about [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com), for instance? The question is how to stop people from listing every old site they come across by Googling for the game's name...

Comment: @Brant how about Thottbot, Wowwiki, Wowpedia, Allakhazam, Boss Killers, MMO-Champion, Ensidia...  Where do you stop?  There is a *very* gradual continuum of "resource" sites vs. more promotional sites.

Comment: That's true. See my answer for a proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Useful, non-official sites are fine to link to, as long as a description of the site is included. The description should state *why* the site is useful. A short sentence is fine.

The problem, of course, is *defining* "useful". It's a fuzzy, subjective concept. (Oh, how we hate subjective concepts!)

I'm going to propose that "useful sites" in this context be defined as "sites that a Gaming.SE community member who is familiar with the game finds useful".

Tag wikis generally don't get the attention they deserve from the community, so we might end up with some crap links in there, but in my opinion this is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why we should limit ourselves to official sources. We wouldn't then get to link to sites such as [nethackwiki.com](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page)...

Answer (score 0):

I got those links from another [glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glitch) question that linked to  [glitch-strategy](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/), and copied the links I found there. I think it is best to link to any major game info page or community whether official or not. Fan-sites are more often likely to delve into matters of the game that the developers/publishers can't or won't talk about.